# Converting mysql column from INT to TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, timestamp

When I was yound and <s>stupid</s> had little experiance, I decided it would be a good idea, to generate timestamps in PHP and store them in `INT` column in my MySQL innodb table. Now, when this table has millions of records and needs some date-based queries, it is time to convert this column to `TIMESTAMP`. How do I do this?

Currenlty, my table looks like this:

```
id (INT) | message (TEXT) | date_sent (INT)
---------------------------------------------
1        | hello?         | 1328287526
2        | how are you?   | 1328287456
3        | shut up        | 1328234234
4        | ok             | 1328678978
5        | are you...     | 1328345324
```

Here are the queries I came up with, to convert `date_sent` column to `TIMESTAMP`:

```
-- creating new column of TIMESTAMP type
ALTER TABLE `pm`
  ADD COLUMN `date_sent2` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

-- assigning value from old INT column to it, in hope that it will be recognized as timestamp
UPDATE `pm` SET `date_sent2` = `date_sent`;

-- dropping the old INT column
ALTER TABLE `pm` DROP COLUMN `date_sent`;

-- changing the name of the column
ALTER TABLE `pm` CHANGE `date_sent2` `date_sent` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

Everything seems correct to me, but when time comes for the `UPDATE`pm`SET`date_sent2`=`date_sent`;`, I get a warning and timestamp value remains empty:

```
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                          |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'date_sent2' at row 1  |
```

What am I doing wrong and is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're nearly there, use [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) instead of directly copying the value.

```
-- creating new column of TIMESTAMP type
ALTER TABLE `pm`
  ADD COLUMN `date_sent2` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

-- Use FROM_UNIXTIME() to convert from the INT timestamp to a proper datetime type
-- assigning value from old INT column to it, in hope that it will be recognized as timestamp
UPDATE `pm` SET `date_sent2` = FROM_UNIXTIME(`date_sent`);

-- dropping the old INT column
ALTER TABLE `pm` DROP COLUMN `date_sent`;

-- changing the name of the column
ALTER TABLE `pm` CHANGE `date_sent2` `date_sent` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
```

Answer (score 1):

This way doesn't require temp field to store timestamp type values, so should be more downtime friendly when altering on huge tables, and it's also avilable with DATE(TIME) type fields (see below).

For convert timestamp or datetime to int see: [Mysql: Convert column from timestamp to int and perform conversion for each update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553079/mysql-convert-column-from-timestamp-to-int-and-perform-conversion-for-each-upda/66066992#66066992)

First we have to cast timestamp type to numeric datetime without punctuation (like 202102060020302), since numeric full form is too long for int to store, should alter field to bigint type (if you need datetime type this would be TEXT type):

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `field` `field` BIGINT NOT NULL;
```

then cast timestamp to numeric datetime (if you need datetime type, CAST() should be removed):

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(`field`) AS UNSIGNED);
```

finally we could change field type to timestamp and mysql will do the rest about converting numeric datetime (if you need datetime type just use DATETIME):

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `field` `field` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html

```
> mysql> SELECT CURTIME(), CURTIME()+0, CURTIME(3)+0;
> +-----------+-------------+--------------+
> | CURTIME() | CURTIME()+0 | CURTIME(3)+0 |
> +-----------+-------------+--------------+
> | 09:28:00  |       92800 |    92800.887 |
> +-----------+-------------+--------------+
> mysql> SELECT NOW(), NOW()+0, NOW(3)+0;
> +---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
> | NOW()               | NOW()+0        | NOW(3)+0           |
> +---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
> | 2012-08-15 09:28:00 | 20120815092800 | 20120815092800.889 |
> +---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
```