# How do I $row time?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so what I would like to do is, lets say i have an account online, and i am looking at all the transactions that have occurred, i want all the dates in asc. time order.
This i have already

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM action ORDER BY time ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    //$date = strtotime('jMy - g:ia', $row[1]);

    echo <<<_END
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td width='40%'><b>ACCOUNT</b></td>
        <td width='20%'><b>TIME</b></td>
        <td width='20%'><b>AMOUNT</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='40%'>$row[0]</td>
        <td width='20%'>$row[1]</td>
        <td width='20%'>$row[2]</td>
    </tr>
</table>
_END;
};
```

The commented out date command is where i think i am going wrong.

Comment: what kind of field is `$row[1]`?

Comment: int. could that be it?

Comment: I guess...  we don't know what your data looks like, or really, what you're asking for.  Is this a table of transactions?  Do you not have a `diatomite` or `timestamp` field?

Comment: the date shows up as a bunch of numbers, yes it is a table of transactions. Either i get todays date or the date that is in my database in one big long number (not in date format, which is what i want).

Comment: try use `mysql_fetch_assoc`, then you can call `$row['YOUR_ROW_TIME_NAME']

Comment: Show me some sample numbers, and i'll be able to better guess how you want he date.

Comment: There's not enough information to diagnose the problem. We don't know the MySQL datatype of the column in question. Also, the normative pattern would be to do a `while (fetch)` loop. The `mysql` interface is deprecated, new development should use `mysqli` or `PDO` interface.

Comment: 1415064235, 1415064041, 1415064030 are three of todays dates that are in my database and the field type is int(10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you are storing epoch times in your database.

First change, is to change it to a `TIMESTAMP` column, which will then render them as readable times in whatever MySQL (i am assuming) client you're using.  This isn't necessary, but it helps.

Second, to convert them to a human-readable date, use the `date` command.

```
 $date = date('jMy - g:ia', $row[1]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

`strtotime` from your sample converts a human-readable date string into that "epoch time" format you already have.  there is also `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` in MySQL which converts from date-looking values to epoch-looking values.

Also, simplify your loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
```

Comment: it changed all my times to 0's ex 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: But your new times should be in a readable format.  Here's a discussion for converting from ints to timestamps for existing data (which I gather is too late).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132461/converting-mysql-column-from-int-to-timestamp