# Mysql: Convert column from timestamp to int and perform conversion for each update

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a existing database column of type `timestamp` that I need to modify to become an `INT(11)`, but in order for this to happen I need to convert each timestamp value as I change it.

Here's my modify statement currently that won't correctly convert the timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
MODIFY COLUMN updated_on INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;
```

Is there a way to provide a conversion function or something to the alter command? Otherwise I was thinking I could

- Create a new column, called *updated_on_temp* of type `INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`
- Convert and copy over all timestamps with:

---

```
UPDATE my_table
SET updated_on_temp = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_on);
```

---

- Delete the `updated_on` column
- Rename `updated_on_temp` to `updated_on`

Is the second way the only efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why? It seems rather silly to convert a value a) to a type which is accessible on demand b) contains less information c) cannot be manipulated without casting back to its original type

Answer (score 2):

This way doesn't require temp field to store timestamp type values, so should be more downtime friendly when altering on huge tables, and it's also avilable with DATE(TIME) type fields by removing UNIX_TIMESTAMP().

For convert int back to timestamp or datetime see: [Converting mysql column from INT to TIMESTAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132461/converting-mysql-column-from-int-to-timestamp/66091010#66091010)

First we have to cast timestamp type to numeric datetime without punctuation (like 202102060020302), since numeric full form is too long for int to store, should alter field to bigint type:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `field` `field` BIGINT NOT NULL;
```

then cast int to numeric datetime and so on timestamp:

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(`field` AS DATETIME));
```

finally trim field type from bigint to int, if you don't care about 2038 year problem:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `field` `field` INT NOT NULL;
```

ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-type-conversion.html

```
> mysql> SELECT CURTIME(), CURTIME()+0, CURTIME(3)+0;
> +-----------+-------------+--------------+
> | CURTIME() | CURTIME()+0 | CURTIME(3)+0 |
> +-----------+-------------+--------------+
> | 09:28:00  |       92800 |    92800.887 |
> +-----------+-------------+--------------+
> mysql> SELECT NOW(), NOW()+0, NOW(3)+0;
> +---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
> | NOW()               | NOW()+0        | NOW(3)+0           |
> +---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
> | 2012-08-15 09:28:00 | 20120815092800 | 20120815092800.889 |
> +---------------------+----------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function

```
TIME_TO_SEC()
```

the converts time value to seconds